# Strip Paragraph Tag

Tags: php

In my image.php I am using this code to grab the image caption of each image.  The problem is a paragraph tag ( `<p>` ) is being added around it and I don't want one to be.  Could somebody tell me how to strip this tag?

```
<?php if ( !empty($post->post_excerpt) ) the_excerpt(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[strip_tags](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) — Strip HTML and PHP tags from a string

```
if (!empty($post->post_excerpt)) {
  $excerpt_raw = strip_tags(get_the_excerpt()); 
  echo $excerpt_raw;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `remove_filter('the_excerpt', 'wp_autop')` which is how I do it.